# Выровнять по центру картинку и текст

Tags: html

```
<span>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="41" height="43" viewBox="0 0 41 43" style="fill:#fff; stroke:#c2c2c2; stroke-width:1px;"><path d="M8,20h26v21H8V20z"/><path d="M21.2,2L2,21h37L21.2,2z"/></svg>
    / <a href="#">Ссылка</a> / <a href="#">2 Ссылка</a>
</span>
```

Подскажите, как выровнять картинку и текст, чтобы они были на одной линии?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uh124Lsc/ так?

Comment: Нет, по центру надо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j4b131po/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8o1t6ekf/

Comment: > Подскажите, как выровнять картинку и текст, чтобы они были на одной линии?  
во всех примерах они не на прямой линии! в последнем варианте мысль пошла вообще не туда

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uh124Lsc/2/ думаю, автору нужно такое выравнивание, спасибо, @soledar10, за код фидла.

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        width="41" height="43" viewBox="0 0 41 43" 
        style="fill:#fff; stroke:#c2c2c2; stroke-width:1px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <path d="M8,20h26v21H8V20z"/><path d="M21.2,2L2,21h37L21.2,2z"/>
    </svg>
        / <a href="#" style="vertical-align: middle;">Ссылка</a> / <a href="#">2 Ссылка</a>
</span>
```

Немного поменял стили для первого a и svg.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Исправил